# Does a BelongsTo/HasOne Association mean the Model that BelongsTo the other must always have an associated Model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, associations

Given the models "Animal" and "Person", where Animal BelongsTo Person and Person HasOne Animal, does this mean that every single Animal instance will **always** have a Person instance associated with the Animal (due to Animal **Belonging To** Person)? And inversely, does this mean that **not** every single Person instance will have an Animal instance associated with it (due to Person **Having One** Animal)?

e.g.:

```typescript
const sequelize = new Sequelize()
const Person = sequelize.define('Person', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
})

const Animal = sequelize.define('Animal', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.UUID,
    primaryKey: true,
    defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
  },
})

Person.hasOne(Animal)
Animal.belongsTo(Person)

async function foo () {
  const animals = await Animal.findAll()
  for (const animal of animals) {
    /**
     * Can I be certain that `person` **always** exists, given that Animal BelongsTo Person?
     * 
     * In other words, does the BelongsTo Association from Animal to Person imply that Animal
     * must **always** have a Person associated with the Animal?
     */
    const person = await animal.getPerson()
  }
  
  const people = await Person.findAll()
  for (const person of people) {
    /**
     * And the inverse; given that Person hasOne Animal, does this imply that not all People
     * will have an Animal associated with them?
     */
    const animal = await person.getAnimal()
  }
}
```

I found some [documentation relevant to my question](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/#one-to-one-relationships) that confused me:

> In principle, both options are a valid way to establish a One-To-One relationship between Foo and Bar. However, when we say something like "there is a One-To-One relationship between Foo and Bar", it is unclear whether or not the relationship is mandatory or optional. **In other words, can a Foo exist without a Bar? Can a Bar exist without a Foo?** The answers to these questions help figuring out where we want the foreign key column to be.

This excerpt from the documentation makes me think that any model that BelongsTo another model must always have an instance of that other model associated with it, whereas inversely, any model that HasOne another model sometimes will not have an instance of that other model associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `Person` has one `Car` and `Car` belongs to `Person`. That means you can see a FK in `Cat` table that refers to that Person ID.

In sequelize, the purpose of your defined "hasOne" and "belongsTo" is to let you do some SQL search with the subject `Person` or `Car` in **Model Querying**.